# Watir clicking nested elements inside a container

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to complete a happy path e-commerce payment test but I cant seem to click on the nested element for credit card to be honest I'm not entirely sure which is the clickable element.

Any help to get this working would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What did you try for it? and share HTML code instead of screenshot...

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I've tried a combination of things I thought it would be best to share html so who ever can help can see exactly what I'm working with rather than a heap of code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

When inputting forms, you typically want to interact with `input` and `select` elements. In this case, you can see that the visible input field is a radio button - ie `<input type="radio">`.

You access radio buttons using the `radio` method and select it by using the `set` method:

```
browser.radio(id: 'cc-payment').set
```

Comment: I've tried this and it looks logical and it should work but I'm getting an exception when I try to run:   unable to locate element, using {:id=>"cc-payment", :tag_name=>"input", :type=>"radio"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)

Comment: changed to: @browser.input(id: 'cc-payment').set  the test passes but the button is not being selected

Comment: The radio button appears to be hidden. May need to make it visible first, or interact with a hidden element(not sure if you can even do that)

Comment: @browser.input(id: 'cc-payment').double_click finally worked so does @browser.radio(id: 'cc-payment').double_click

Answer (score 0):

The `element` you want to click is the `input` with type `radio`. You should be able to do something like:

```rb
driver.find_element(:css, "input[id='cc-payment'][value='creditCard']").click
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious if clicking on the parent item would resolve.

@browser.input(id: 'cc-payment').parent.click

If the div registers the click and sets the input then this might work. You should be able to manually verify this beahviour by clicking outside of the radial and seeing if it selects.